# Wave superposition proof?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, waves, superposition, linear-systems

I've just learned the superposition of waves. It got me thinking.... For example, if we're talking about waves in a string, can't we express all the things that happens on the rope using just $F=ma$ and some other mechanic equations? Then shouldn't we be able to prove the superposition of a wave in this manner? Using basic Newtonian mechanics? I don't think that this will be possible to be done on waves like light....

All this above was for one thing; how do I prove the superposition of a wave? Is it provable?

Comment: The proof of superposition is that the wave equation describing the wave propagation is a linear differential equstion. That insures that the sum of two solutions is also a solution. That is true for light waves as well as long as they are not propagating in a nonlinear optical medium.

Comment: Are you familiar with differential equations? The answer you want is quite simple if you are familiar with differential equations, but may require more hand waving otherwise.

Comment: I'm just a highschool student. I've learned most of Newtonian mechanics involving single variable calculus. But not differential equation... I could ask my dad about it though.. My dad teaches differential equation in college. (But not physics!!)

Comment: You know, in high school textbooks, they just state this as 'a principal'.... Which was very unsatisfactory for me

Comment: I have a question though; then what we define as wave must satisfy the differential equation that was talked previously??

Comment: Then, in case of light. Shouldn't we first prove that light 'waves' can be considered as 'waves' because

Comment: They satisfy the differential equation for a wave??        PS thank you for answering to my questions which may seem very primitive(?) to you :)

Comment: Here is an example of superposition http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/waves/Lesson-3/Interference-of-Waves   and simple linear differential equations http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Linear.aspx

Comment: You are welcome....and very lucky in your choice of a father :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For example, if we're talking about waves in a string, can't we express all the things that happens on the rope using just F=ma and some other mechanic equations?

Wave equations **do** come from Newton's law; in particular, if you apply such equations of motion to each infinitesimal piece of the string and include the tensions in all directions, you exactly end up with the wave equation
$$
\frac{1}{v^2}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial t^2}-\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} = g(x,t).
$$

> how do I prove the superposition of a wave? Is it provable?

A mathematical property of the above equation is that, given any two solutions, their sum is a solution too. You can just plug the sum in and check that it still fulfills the equation provided the two initial solutions do.